# Finding index of a row in zoo object in R

Tags: indexing, zoo

I have a zoo object with index of POSIXct and it contains `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

My data is look like this:

```
2008-01-03 13:55:00 794.61 60.10000
2008-01-03 14:25:00 794.49 60.10000
2008-01-03 14:55:00 795.91 60.10000
2008-01-03 15:27:00 796.02 60.10000
2008-01-04 15:56:00 792.10 60.10000
2008-01-04 16:21:00 794.24 60.10000
2008-01-04 16:40:00 794.66 60.10000
2008-01-04 18:20:00 793.02 60.10000
2008-01-05 18:35:00 793.06 60.10000
2008-01-05 21:59:00 793.06 60.40000
2008-01-05 22:29:00 793.06 60.00000
2008-01-06 22:55:00 793.02 60.00000
2008-01-06 00:04:00 792.85 60.00000
2008-01-07 00:29:00 792.85 60.46667
2008-01-07 00:54:00 794.02 60.46667
```

I need to find Index number or first row in day *2008-01-05* and it must be 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this method work !

min(which(format(index(MyData), "%Y-%m-%d") == '2008-01-05')

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `which` with a minimum function in case there are multiple rows:

```
min(which(yourdata[, 1] == "2008-01-05"))
```